# Find a string that contains X but not Y

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to perform regular expression operations on urls. I have these two routes on my site:

- domain.tld/clermont-ferrand/63000-cedex-01/
- domain.tld/clermont-ferrand/63000-cedex-01/in-a-25-km-radius/

I am using the regular expression `[0-9a-z\-]+` to match 63000-cedex-01 (note that 63000-cedex-01 can be any postal code formatted with hyphens instead of spaces).

Now the problem comes up when someone tries to access an url like this:

domain.tld/clermont-ferrand/in-a-25-km-radius/

The regular expression will consider this route as valid, which is something I don't want.

Is it possible to tell regex to search for a hyphen separated alphanumerical pattern that doesn't contain "in-a-25-km-radius".

I tried these two regex and they don't work:

- `((?!in-a-\d+-(km|mile|miles)-radius)|[0-9a-z\-]+)`
- `(?(?=[0-9a-z\-]+)([0-9a-z\-]+)|(in-a-\d+-(km|mile|miles)-radius))`

**EDIT**

OK basically on my route file for my MVC framework I have these two routes:

> /event/{status:(ongoing|past|upcoming)}/{category_slug:[a-z-]+}-event/in/{city_slug:[a-z-]+}/{postal_code_slug:[0-9a-z-]+}/

which matches a path like:

> /event/ongoing/music-event/in/clermont-ferrand/63000-cedex-01/

and

> /event/{status:(ongoing|past|upcoming)}/{category_slug:[a-z-]+}-event/in/{city_slug:[a-z-]+}/{postal_code_slug:[0-9a-z-]+}/in-a-{radius:\d+}-{unit:(km|mile|miles)}-radius/

which matches a path like:

> /event/upcoming/film-event/in/beverly-hills/90210/in-a-40-miles-radius/

Unfortunately, the first route also matches:

> /event/past/manga-and-anime-event/in/montreal/in-a-200-km-radius/

**EDIT**

The regex should match strings like these:

- 9600
- ax-85000
- ad327
- 36505-962
- biqq-1zz
- gx11-1aa

and **not** match strings like these:

- in-a-200-km-radius
- in-a-1-mile-radius
- in-a-85-miles-radius

Comment: How can you match `63000-cedex-01` with `[a-z\-]+`? It is impossible. What is your real regex? Show the code where it is used and explain what result you need to get per each provided input.

Comment: you are correct. I fixed it!

Comment: You've fixed nothing.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ij3CTZ/1

Comment: You know what your maximum radius is. And you know the possible length of the zip codes. why do you use +?

Comment: I don't have a maximum radius and I can't rely on wikipedia to tell me what the maximum length of a zip code is since it's wrong about French zip code; it could be wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to tell regex to search for a hyphen separated
>   alphanumerical pattern that doesn't contain "in-a-25-km-radius".

Try this:

```
\A(?!in-a-25-km-radius)[\w-]++
```

Comment: it doesn't match hyphen separated alphanumerical patterns. in fact as far as I can tell it doesn't match anything

Comment: May be some misunderstanding take place.

Comment: PCRE operates with "subject string", "pattern" and "match" termins.  Show exact subject strings that need to be match, than show exact subject strings that need to nomatch.  After that I can write a pattern.  Your previous posts don't contain exact subject strings.

Comment: try  `^(?!in-a-\d++-(?>km|miles?+)-radius)[\w-]++`  You can ensure that it work at https://regex101.com/r/XyVXRT/1